# How to communicate with a bluetooth peripheral that does not have a PIN?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am trying to create an Android application to control a bluetooth device. But the device does not have any PIN set.
When I try to connect with "device.connectGatt" (or any other method) , pairing starts.
Then the phone shows the PIN dialog requesting for a PIN.
Unfortunately , the device does not have a PIN. So whatever I enter, it is rejected.
The prompt on Android phone does not allow null/none entry.

As I read bluetooth documentation, I understand that if I can set the client IO capability to "no input no display" , I should be able to pair without a PIN.
However I could not find a way to do it in Android BLE libraries. (there is a method in Android things but I can't use it since I am working with Android phone)

I read similar questions and see that some users were able to pair without a PIN by using "just works"
But I can't find how this works. What is the method for setting "just works"

I am using a phone with Android 12 and of course targetting API 31. But I can target a lower API if there is a solution there.

What can I do to communicate/pair with a device with NO PIN ?

thanks

Comment: Most likely the remote device is initiating pairing in that case.

Comment: it both accepts inbound and outbound pairing requests. But I need to initiate from my app. Is  there a solution ?

Comment: Android never starts the pairing process on its own unless required, for example when the remote device requires pairing. If you want to manually trigger pairing on the Android side, you can call `createBond` on the `BluetoothDevice` object. Whether passkey or "just works" will be used depends on the advertised i/o capabilities of the remote device.

Comment: the remote device advertises IO capability as "no input / no display" , so I am guessing Android is requiring PIN. But there is no PIN on the remote device. So what can I do ? If what you say is correct, then why do I have a PIN prompt on Android ?

Comment: phone sends 
    IO Capability: Keyboard, Display (0x04)
this is same in both "pair from phone" and "pair from remote device" scenarios.

Comment: Android does not show and does not require passkey dialog if the remote device says "no input no output". Please post the hci log of the SMP messages if this still is the case.

Comment: ok after your message I double checked the response from the camera. It is not "no input no display" always, it sends "display yes/no" for this direction. So how can I change the behaviour from my Android app ?

Comment: Do you mean your camera says "display yes/no" although it doesn't have such capabilities?

Comment: the camera has a display but it does not show any PIN information or other prompt while pairing. And yes it says "display yes/no" , but the problem is that on Android I get a PIN prompt most of the time. Sometimes it turns to a yes/no question but does not pair in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your camera initiates the pairing process since you don't do it from the Android side.

When pairing is initiated, both devices exchange input/output capabilities. From these two the "best", i.e. most secure pairing method is chosen. For example if one device has a display and the other a keyboard, a new randomly generated passkey is shown on the device with the display and the user shall input that passkey on the device with the keyboard.

Android always advertises the i/o capabilities "keyboard, display". This cannot be modified by any API.

If your camera says it has display capabilities but it does not show any passkey on its display, then blame the camera producer for not following the standard.

Comment: so you say  I am stuck with this situation. Actually the camera is a Insta 360 camera and I really don't understand why it has an open bluetooth access when  there is no accessory utilizing it. And if the implementation is wrong (no PIN but requires use of it somehow) then why do we even have this bluetooth access ?